# There is no application set to open the URL rstf3://

Tags: macos, network, url

I've been getting this popup every day for the past few days...

> There is no application set to open the URL rstf3://

[image]

I cannot figure out what is generating it, nor what an rstf3 URL might even be.
Google came up blank, Console shows no reference to it at all; I had hoped it might at least give a clue as to what app was trying to request it.

iGetter is the only new app on here which could possibly fit the timeline; I'll try quitting it tonight & see if the message no longer appears, but I'd really like to know what it is & what app type might be used to handle it if it's a legit request.

Running OS X 10.11.5 on a Mac Pro 5,1 with both ethernet & Wifi connectivity, if relevant.

Comment: What happens if you try and open it with a text editor? Does it show anything useful?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that - I'll have to wait until next time I get the popup, as I dismissed this morning's after I asked this question :/

Comment: Does it happen regularly, at specific intervals?

Comment: It happens overnight, every night for the past few days. The only app I have set to run overnight specifically is MacScan 3, but I've had that several months with no issue. The machine never sleeps, so I have no 'wake schedule ' I could check.

Comment: You might be able to track it down with "lsof" to see what process is accessing the dialogue API.

Comment: another good idea - I'll give that a shot next time it pops up

Comment: I'm going to have to park this question for now. After happening consistently for a week... it's stopped, before I had any chance to investigate further.