# There is no application set to open the URL

Tags: finder, applications, google-chrome

Similar to [There is no application set to open the URL rstf3://](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/241780/there-is-no-application-set-to-open-the-url-rstf3), I am getting the following error when clicking on https://miro.com/* links from another application (Slack):

[image: There is no application set to open the URL miroapp://]

> There is no application set to open the URL miroapp://

I uninstalled the miro desktop application "as clean as possible" with [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) but I am still seeing the issue after rebooting my MacOS (latest).

I also checked with [SwitfDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps) but I can not find any association related to miroapp.

Would be great not to have some funky workaround but really fix the root cause. Surely this is some simple setting somewhere? I think with windows this would be the registry/regedit.

I do not want to have the miro desktop app installed.

Comment: What exactly are you doing that generates this dialog box? What version of **macOS** are you running? (Looks like **macOS Big Sur**) Is the app in question Miro Desktop from [https://miro.com/apps/](https://miro.com/apps/)?

Comment: To extend off of that, this alert is what happens *because* you uninstalled the application, then tried to open a link that relied on the application. Knowing what you were doing is critical to understanding why you're seeing this alert.

Comment: Thanks good feedback, completely forgot about mentioning how I am getting the issue 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Miro actually has a Help article to solve this issue: https://help.miro.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019244239-How-to-Disable-Miro-Desktop-App-Pop-up-in-Your-Browser

Here's the important steps:

For Mac users

Step 1. Delete (uninstall) the Desktop app from your computer.

Step 2. Rollback the setting ‘Always open URL in the Miro App’ in your browser. Here's how you can do that in Chrome and Firefox.
For Chrome:

- Close all Chrome + Miro windows before starting (use **Cmd + Q** to quit the browser)
- Open a finder window > press **Command + Shift + G** > enter the following path into the search box: **~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Preferences**.
- Open Preferences in a text editor Search for https://miro.com":{"miroapp":true}
- Remove https://miro.com":{"miroapp":true} Save changes Restart Chrome browser.

If you use several Google profiles, you will need to edit Preferences in all catalogs. For this, on step 2, you will need to open ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome and change Preferences in folders Profile 1, Profile 2, etc.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @grg thanks for the tip! I've added the important info to my answer. 

Comment: @DanielMargheim thanks for this! Fixed my issue with MS Teams on Brave Browser, too :-)